# Is there anyway to view sorted files by type in a directory with the ls command on Mac terminal?

Tags: bash, command-line

When using "ls", you see the contents in a directory, in terms of alphabetic order (suppose there's no subdirectory). Is there anyway to view the contents with the ls command, while the results are sorted in terms of the different file types? i.e. files with the same type will be next to each other.

Comment: If you use `cat $(ls *.*)` you can view the contents of all files in a directory in a continuous stream according to the order specified by `ls`. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: What should happen with binary executables? PDF files? MP3 audio? Are you sure you want to see their contents? I mean, you'll get a whole bunch of "random" output if one of those are in your directory, rendering the final result effectively useless.

Answer (score 0):

With `ls` only, I don’t think so. you would have to  use `file`and `sort`, probably piped together. Maybe you could print each file with its file type, use `awk` to sort by one column?

To get the files

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do
  echo "$f",$(file "$f")> tmpfile
done
```

To sort and print them:

```
$ cat tmpfile | awk -F, '{ print $1,$0 }'  | sort
```

This might work, I'm not entirely sure but it should work in theory.

Comment: You've got non-ASCII quotation marks. Also, why echoing `$f` and `$(file $f)` if the output of `file $f` already contains the filename?

Comment: I fixed the variable quoting. Non-ASCII quotes are because I’m writing this on an iPad.